# Timezone offset of any time using using JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dst

I am using `var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` to get the current timezone offset of user.

But, how can I get the timezone offset for any future time?

This is required because the timezone offset is different when `DST` is enabled/disabled.So I cant assume the same offset for future time.

Comment: Any future time for what? That client?

Comment: This is for creating an event for the user in future time.Yes for that client.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, even if you did, how would you know he didn't moved?

Comment: I will create the event in user's current timezone. If I know the timezone offset for the user for event's time, I can convert it to UTC at server properly. I will always show the event in user's local time, so I think it does not matter if user moves

Answer (score 2):

This question confused me into thinking that perhaps `getTimezoneOffset()` wouldn't correctly get the timezone offset for future dates already. It does.

As far as `JavaScript` is concerned, you give it a milliseconds since the epoch date, which is ubiquitous, and it gives you the offset in local time *as it will be on that date*, because all the Date functionality cares about is taking a universal date/time and passing back a date that will make sense to the local user, unless you specifically ask it for the universal equivalent, with methods like `getUTCDate()`.

So running

```
var summer = new Date(1403170847000);
alert('Summer offset=' + summer.getTimezoneOffset());

var winter = new Date(1419500175000);
alert('Winter offset=' + winter.getTimezoneOffset());
```

in a console where the local time includes a DST period, reports for me in the UK an offset of -60 (i.e. GMT+1) for the date in the summer, and 0 (i.e. GMT) for the date in the winter.

http://jsfiddle.net/SX9SN/